# What is the equivalent of Tcl's 'uplevel' in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, stack, tcl, eval

Tcl's [`uplevel`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/uplevel.htm) command will `eval` the supplied string in a higher stack frame than the current subroutine.

Is there an equivalent in Javascript?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cases of use of `uplevel` in Tcl are done in JS by getting the caller to pass in an anonymous function. (With trickery over variable scoping sometimes needed.)

```
proc iterSquares {var script} {
    upvar 1 $var v
    for {set i 0} {$i <= 10} {incr i} {
        set v [expr {$i ** 2}]
        uplevel 1 $script
    }
}

iterSquares x {
    puts "I've got a $x"
}
```

```
function iterSquares(callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        callback(i ** 2);
    }
}

iterSquares(function(x) {
    console.log("I've got a", x);
});
```

But there's no real equivalent to the more general forms, which are in many ways more like Lisp macro expansion (though not the same either).

Comment: Basically, if you see `upvar` or `uplevel` with a level parameter of anything other than `1` (caller's context) or `#0` (global context), or with variable names or scripts that are not simply supplied by the caller, _watch out_ as the code is doing something tricky that can't really be described in most other languages. You might also see `0` (current context) with `upvar` for doing local variable aliases, but you probably don't want to replicate those in Javascript due to the different fundamental object model.